# Implementing merge sort in Java: Only zeroes

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to implement some sorting algorithms in Java working on int-arrays as an educational process. I currently try to wrap my head around merge sort. Yesterday I got pretty far, with a result of an array of the correct size, but only containing zeroes. Today I started new from the ground, and now I'm stuck at the same point. ^^
Here is my code:

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array) {
    if (array.length < 2) {
        return array;
    }
    int left = 0;
    int right = array.length;
    int p = array.length / 2;
    int[] lArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, left, p);
    int[] rArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, p, right);
    lArray = mergeSort(lArray);
    rArray = mergeSort(rArray);
    return merge(lArray, rArray);
}

private static int[] merge(int[] lArray, int[] rArray) {
    int[] result = new int[lArray.length + rArray.length];
    int idx = 0;
    int rIdx = 0;
    int lIdx = 0;
    while (lIdx < lArray.length - 1 && rIdx < rArray.length - 1) {
        if (lArray[lIdx] < rArray[rIdx]) {
            result[idx] = lArray[lIdx];
            lIdx++;
        } else if (lArray[lIdx] >= rArray[rIdx]) {
            result[idx] = rArray[rIdx];
            rIdx++;
        }
        idx++;
    }
    if (lIdx < (lArray.length - 1)) {
        result[idx] = lArray[lIdx + 1];
    } else if (rIdx < (rArray.length - 1)) {
        result[idx] = rArray[rIdx + 1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I think it's pretty OKly-styled and readable. So, all you algorith- and Java-cracks out there, what am I missing? Debugging points toward the merge method, but I can't quite pin it down, so I publish this as-is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you simply tried to debug this step by step with a short array to find where the zeroes are coming from ? Debugger is your best friend

Comment: You can't consider something readable with variable names like `lIdx`, `rIdx`, `p`

Comment: I am constantly trying to debug it doing exactly what you suggest - as I said, I see hints that I'm getting the merge-method wrong, but I'm not sure where exactly.

Oh, and you're right about the one variable name p. I stuck to the pseudo-code I have from my professor and forgot to comment on that. Yet, I find readability suffers more from overlong statements than from kind of obvious abbreviations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in your `merge` method :

First of all, your while loop ignores the last element of the left and right arrays. You should change

```
while (lIdx < lArray.length - 1 && rIdx < rArray.length - 1)
```

to

```
while (lIdx < lArray.length && rIdx < rArray.length)
```

Second of all, After that while loop, you need two more while loops to add the tail of the left array or the tail of the right array. Instead you only add a single element.

Replace

```
if (lIdx < (lArray.length - 1)) {
    result[idx] = lArray[lIdx + 1];
} else if (rIdx < (rArray.length - 1)) {
    result[idx] = rArray[rIdx + 1];
}
```

with

```
while (lIdx < lArray.length) {
    result[idx++] = lArray[lIdx++];
} 
while (rIdx < rArray.length) {
    result[idx++] = rArray[rIdx++];
}
```

Comment: In the second whiles add idx++ so: result[idx++] = rArray[rIdx++]; and result[idx++] = lArray[lIdx++];

Comment: @RaulGuiu Thanks. Missed that

Comment: Why the second while loop? The length difference can only be one, dictated by the logic of the calling method. If `merge` was public, I would agree, that one might be tempted to call it with arrays of arbitrary lengths, but it is private.

But, hell yes, I leave out the last element in both arrays. m( Thank you, I'll check your fix (and eventually mark your reply as correct) as soon as I get to it.

Comment: @Aarkon This has nothing to do with the length difference. Suppose, for example, all the elements of rArray are smaller than all the elements of lArray. The first loop will copy all the elements of rArray to the merged array and terminate once rIdx reaches rArray.length. At this point you have to iterate over all the elements of lArray and add them to the merged array.

Comment: You were right! There was my mistake. Thank you and everyone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (lIdx < (lArray.length - 1)) {
    result[idx] = lArray[lIdx + 1];
} else if (rIdx < (rArray.length - 1)) {
    result[idx] = rArray[rIdx + 1];
}
```

This part is a bit strange. Why do you just copy one remaining element into your result array? You should copy all the remaining elements from either lArray or rArray into your result. Use 'while' instead of 'if'.

Comment: This part is meant only to clean up after the while-statement above already walks through the whole partial arrays and one is longer than the other.
The length difference can only be one by the logic of the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
public class MergeSort {

public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array) {
    if (array.length < 2) {
        return array;
    }
    int left = 0;
    int right = array.length;
    int p = array.length / 2;
    int[] lArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, left, p);
    int[] rArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, p, right);
    //printArray(lArray); seems ok
    //printArray(rArray); seems ok
    lArray = mergeSort(lArray);
    rArray = mergeSort(rArray);
    return merge(lArray, rArray);
}

private static int[] merge(int[] lArray, int[] rArray) {
    /*System.out.println("Ive got");
    printArray(lArray);
    printArray(rArray); seems ok*/
    int[] result = new int[lArray.length + rArray.length];
    int index = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int leftIndex = 0;
    while (leftIndex < lArray.length && rightIndex < rArray.length) { //TODO
        if (lArray[leftIndex] < rArray[rightIndex]) {
            result[index] = lArray[leftIndex];

            leftIndex++;
            index++;
            //} else if (lArray[leftIndex] >= rArray[rightIndex]) { // You don't have to check it!!!
        } else {
            System.out.println("2 left index " + leftIndex + " index " + index);
            result[index] = rArray[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
            index++;
        }
    }
    while (leftIndex < (lArray.length)) { // TODO
        result[index] = lArray[leftIndex];
        index++;
        leftIndex++;
    }
    while (rightIndex < (rArray.length)) { // TODO
        result[index] = rArray[rightIndex];
        index++;
        rightIndex++;
    }
    System.out.println("Returning ");
    printArray(result);
    return result;
}

public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
    for (int i : arr)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {2, 1, 3, 4, 0, -1};
    printArray(arr);
    arr = mergeSort(arr);
    printArray(arr);
}
}
```

What was wrong is marked with `//TODO`